# How do I know which way my RAM chips should be facing when I click them in?

Tags: memory

I have a **asus p5b mx** motherboard and just bought two 2GB **pc2-5300u-555** chips. I don't remember which way the one's I took out were facing and it seems I can click these in either way.

Does it matter which way they are facing when I put them in? How do I know?

Comment: Whichever way it will fit in!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a notch near the middle (you can see it on the photo below) but slightly offset that matches the slot on the motherboard, to ensure that it only fits one way, Just line it up.

[image]

Comment: Beat me by one second! Argh!

Comment: Obviously, some memory is notched differently... But the point is pretty clear. If you played with Lego you've got this problem owned to an extreme.

Answer (score 2):

If you can click them in either way then either you are using *way* too much force or something is *seriously* wrong. I would stop immediately and have someone more familiar with computer assembly take a look at what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it matters which way you connect critical hardware,
there is always a notch involved to guide correct connects and prevent the wrong ones.

Besides, it almost always matters which way you connect.